# How to create an instance of C# class with a property whose setter is private..from F#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

So I am working on a F# project, and need to access some C# classes. In particular, one of the C# class looks like this:

```
class LoginRequest {
  public string Scope {get; private set;}
}
```

Now with C# itself, an instance can be created easily with object initializer: `new LoginRequest() {Scope = "all"}` for example.

However, I could not figure out a way to create such an instance from F#. Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried `LoginRequest( Scope = "all" )`?

Comment: Actually, no, the property cannot be initialized in C# either, from the outside like you showed. Private means private, in both C# and F#. It means the class itself is responsible for setting this property, so you need to figure out how the class is meant to be used. I would start with the constructor(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the given example there is no easy (non-reflection, see below) way, i.e. private setters are inaccessible from C# and F#:

```cs
new LoginRequest { Scope = "s" }; // CS0272 The property or indexer 'LoginRequest.Scope' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible
```

```ml
LoginRequest(Scope = "s") // error FS0495: The object constructor 'LoginRequest' has no argument or settable return property 'Scope'.
```

For accessing the private setter, you could use

```ml
let r = LoginRequest()
typeof<LoginRequest>.GetProperty("Scope").GetSetMethod(true).Invoke(r, [| "scope" |])
r.Scope // scope
```

However, I would strongly discourage the use of reflection. The most obvious reason being that you lose compile time safety.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. 

I don't have a choice though, the `LoginRequest` here is from `octokit.net`, github's client SDK.

Comment: Interesting, is this type from some dependency of OctoKit? I can't find it: https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/search?q=LoginRequest

Comment: Or is it https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/6a0d4042634c572b7e5e488c19d4bd45f5f66773/Octokit/Models/Request/OauthLoginRequest.cs#L60 ?

Comment: If it is, there's no "initializer" in F#, you'd need to split it: `let r = OauthLoginRequest("cId"); r.Scopes.Add "scope"`

Comment: That is, there's no equivalent for the C# shortcut `var r = new OauthLoginRequest("cId") { Scopes = { "scope" } };` (note the extra curly brackets around "scope")